# Why in c# Exception class does not have a constructor with 1 Exception argument?

Tags: c#, exception

`System.Exception` class has 4 constructors:

```
public Exception();
public Exception(string message);
protected Exception(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
public Exception(string message, Exception innerException);
```

Why it does not have this constructor?

```
public Exception(Exception innerException);
```

This is one place where it would have been helpful.

I have a static method to get an open connection:

```
public static DbConnection GetOpenConnection(string dataProvider, string connectionString) 
{
   DbConnection dbConnection = GetDbProviderFactory(dataProvider).CreateConnection();
   dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
   dbConnection.Open();
   return dbConnection;
}
```

I want this method to throw a custom exception `GetOpenConnectionException` if any error occured.

So I created the custom exception `GetOpenConnectionException`:

```
public class GetOpenConnectionException : Exception
{
   public GetOpenConnectionException(string message) : base(message)
   {
   }
   public GetOpenConnectionException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
   {
   }
}
```

Since `Exception` does not have a constructor `public Exception(Exception innerException)`, I cannot have this code in `GetOpenConnectionException`:

```
public GetOpenConnectionException(Exception innerException) : base(innerException)
{
}
```

So I am forced to code the `GetOpenConnection()` method this way:

```
public static DbConnection GetOpenConnection(string dataProvider, string connectionString) 
{
   try 
   {
      DbConnection dbConnection = GetDbProviderFactory(dataProvider).CreateConnection();
      dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
      dbConnection.Open();
      return dbConnection;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw new GetOpenConnectionException("", e);
   }
}
```

What I wanted is to code the `GetOpenConnection()` method this way:

```
public static DbConnection GetOpenConnection(string dataProvider, string connectionString) 
{
   try 
   {
      DbConnection dbConnection = GetDbProviderFactory(dataProvider).CreateConnection();
      dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
      dbConnection.Open();
      return dbConnection;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw new GetOpenConnectionException(e);
   }
}
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Any reason you can't just do `public GetOpenConnectionException(Exception innerException) : base("", innerException)`?

Comment: Basically you are just wrapping an exception inside another exception, adding a message helps to say why you are wrapping it, otherwise just rethrow the inner exception. If you aren't adding value to the exception, don't wrap it.

Comment: What do you gain by rethrowing the exception here?

Comment: `GetOpenConnectionException` will only be thrown from this method and will tells me that error happened because of connection issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers provide good ways to achieve what you are asking for, but I believe the heart of your question is: "Why didn't this exist in the first place?"

Exceptions are normally thrown when a routine's assumptions or prerequisites about the resources it uses and the arguments it asks for are not met. The exception thrown should help the caller (or programmer) understand what assumption or prerequisite was not met, so that they can handle it accordingly or fix their code. The message is a critical part of that communication. I would even hazard a guess that if the Exception class didn't need to be serializable, there wouldn't even be an empty constructor!

Nesting an exception inside of another implies that the nested exception is the cause of the container exception. (The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/804f22sf(v=vs.110).aspx) for that particular constructor of the Exception class points to this a bit.) If you simply pass an inner exception without any message, that effectively translates to "I am going to throw an exception which provides no additional information beyond it's type."  That's not very helpful, and it would probably have been nicer to simply let the original exception be thrown.

Here's one way you could provide a more meaningful message:

```
public static DbConnection GetOpenConnection(string dataProvider, string connectionString) 
{
   try 
   {
      DbConnection dbConnection = GetDbProviderFactory(dataProvider).CreateConnection();
      dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
      dbConnection.Open();
      return dbConnection;
   }
   catch (Exception e) // consider changing this to a more specific type of exception, as an error with .Open() is not the only way it could fail
   {
      // provide a meaningful message to the caller about the context of this error
      var message = string.Format("An error occurred while trying to connect to the data provider {0} with the connection string {1}.", dataProvder, connectionString);
      throw new GetOpenConnectionException(message, e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. "Why didn't this exist in the first place?" was really my question and you have answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

```
   public GetOpenConnectionException(Exception innerException) : base("", innerException)
   {
   }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Here you clear the exception message. If you try to get the ex.Message you always got an empty string.

Comment: Maybe `: base(null, innerException)` is better?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Piotr Dory's answer, you could do this:

```
public GetOpenConnectionException(Exception innerException) :
    base(innerException.message, innerException)
{
}
```

This way you're actually passing something meaningful into the base constructor.

As to *why* there isn't a constructor that only takes an Exception argument... it doesn't seem there is actually a good reason.  They easily could have.